# How do I correctly install ambethia/recaptcha with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

I have done the following steps:

Added to gemfile:

```
gem "recaptcha"
```

Added to config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = 'MyKeyHere'
  config.private_key = 'MyKeyHere'
end
```

Added to view:

```
= raw recaptcha_tags
```

Ran:
    bundle install

...then restarted server. The result?

```
undefined local variable or method `recaptcha_tags' for #<#<Class:0x1053baaa0>:0x1053b69c8>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The gem's README](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#readme) says to, in Rails 2 (yes, I know you're in 3—just a minute :D), include the following line to require the gem:

```
config.gem "recaptcha", :lib => "recaptcha/rails"
```

The important bit to note here is the instruction that Rails should essentially end up running `require 'recaptcha/rails'`. Your current Gemfile doesn't have that specified, so it may very well only be loading in the gem's core classes, not the Rails-specific tie-ins.

Try:

```
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

Comment: Thanks, it returns the following error when starting the server or running bundle install: You passed :lib as an option for gem 'recaptcha', but it is invalid.

Comment: @TLK: durr. It's `require` in the Gemfile, not `lib`. Sorry; edited to match :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following gem into your gemfile.

```
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```